# Powershell: Passing an Inner Codeblock - confuses arguments

Tags: function, powershell, recursion, parameter-passing, codeblocks

I've created a recursive function to format my console outputs, but I've run into trouble trying to pass any arguments to the next recursion.

Here is the relevant part of the function:

```
function exo {
    Param(
        [Parameter]$function,
        [Parameter][string]$message,
        [Parameter]$alt,
        [switch]$continue, [switch]$return, [switch]$skip
    )
    Process {
   ...
        if($alt) {
            $out = exo $alt -return:$return -continue:$continue
        }
   ...
```

The problem is that when I pass a second exo in a block to the first, powershell includes everything as part of that block, even the message and switches.

Here is an example:

```
exo { write-host "This block executes first" } "Message for this block" `
    { exo { write-host "This block executes next" } "But the closing bracket doesn't register, and this message is executed as code" }
```

Escaping the bracket doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there any way to pass arguments into a recursive function?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that your aren't use the [Parameter()] attribute correctly.  The parens are required:

```
function exo {
    Param(
        [Parameter()]$function,
        [Parameter()][string]$message,
        [Parameter()]$alt,
        [switch]$continue, 
        [switch]$return, 
        [switch]$skip
    )
    ...
}
```

After fixing that it seems to recurse, although on the second time through `exo` $alt is $null so it doesn't execute $function again AFAICT based on your code snippet.